# Adding dynamic script resource to a page

Tags: javascript

In the application I'm developing I need to include some javascript files dynamically after the page is loaded. How to acheive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load a script resource dynamically using the following function

```
function loadScript(src){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Here we are creating a script element dynamically and add that to the DOM structure of the page.

If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can use the [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method to fetch a script resource dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Add dynamic script resource to a page

```
function loadScript(src){
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = src;
document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```